# XSLT2 Selecting subset of a group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am somewhat new to using groups and want to be able to select a subset of teh group by using position().

I already have this code working as I want (creating the groups as needed and the correct output.)

```
<xsl:template match="Locations">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Location" group-by="Country">
            <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="current-grouping-key()">
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            <tr>
                <td class="country"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="City">
                <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <tr>
                    <td class="city"><xsl:value-of select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

If I wanted to just get the 2nd through 4th Country tags, how would I go about doing that? I tried position(), but instead of getting a number, I am getting the grouping-key value, e.g., CA.

This is the source XML:

`<Locations>
    <Location>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <City>New York</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <City>Houston</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>MX</Country>
        <City>Cancun</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>CH</Country>
        <City>Zurich</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>CA</Country>
        <City>Toronto</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>DE</Country>
        <City>Berlin</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>JP</Country>
        <City>Tokyo</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <City>London</City>
    </Location>
    <Location>
        <Country>CA</Country>
        <City>Edmonton</City>
    </Location>
</Locations>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the output you are expecting in this case? It might also help if you showed your attempt at using `position()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted to just get the 2nd through 4th Country tags, how would I
>   go about doing that?

I guess you would do:

```
<xsl:template match="Locations">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Location" group-by="Country">
                <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() ge 2 and position() le 4">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="country">
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="City">
                        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="city">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking I would have to put a delimiter on the group-by selection, something like this: group-by="Country[position() ge 2 and position() le 4]"

Comment: The actual syntax aside, if you group by `position() ge 2 and position() le 4` you will get 2 groups: one for which the expression is true, and one for which it is false. Together, the two groups will contain **all** the original Locations. Note also that the position would be calculated before sorting.